# Laravel 5.3 : Error Sending mail using gmail SMTP while works fine in localhost

Tags: smtp, gmail, laravel-5.3

I have searched this question and got many answers like to use

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
```

and checked gmail settings to allow less secure apps.

and it works but its not sending mails from my gmail account.Does anyone knows how to send mails actually from gmail account.

Below is my .env file code:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=test@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=***
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=test@gmail.com
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_NAME=Test
```

Gmail credentials are correct but I am getting this error:

```
Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials b91sm1640930otc.29 - gsmtp
"
```

I am shocked that `MAIL_DRIVER=smtp` works fine with localhost while I need to change it to `MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail` while on hosted server.Please help if anyone can explain this behaviour.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Did you go through the support link given in the error message. My guess its because your account not allowing less secure apps. https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255

Comment: Yeah it is allowed for less secure app. Sorry I forgot to mention it in question.